# Error 419 when sending POST request to domain from subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain, csrf

I receive error 419 in the response after sending a request to example.com from admin.example.com, and vice versa.

I changed `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),` to `'domain' => '.example.com',` in config/session.php, however that did not seem to change anything.

admin.example.com CSRF code:

```html
. . .
</head>
<body>
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    @include('_nav')
    . . .
```

I expect the response to be JSON related to the request, but I actually get a Laravel HTML response that says "Page Expired". There's obviously something wrong with the CSRF token that I generate.

The request:

[image]

Comment: Did you clear your browser cookies after changing to `'domain' => '.example.com'`?

Comment: Yeah, I cleared cookies after changing it. All domains are ".example.com" in the cookies.

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of the `cookies` tab under `application` in the chrome dev tools?

Comment: Here's the cookies: [imgur](https://i.imgur.com/TshBjNj.png)

Comment: Found out that it's not because of the CSRF token, it's because the cookies aren't able to be accessed from the page when the request is sent from the subdomain. How do I fix that? I return `dd($_COOKIE)` as the response and it shows `[]`.

Comment: Hello @d0x, I am having the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CSRF token, In case you have a form to send the request, you can include the

```
<form>
    @csrf
</form>
```

token inside that and if you don't have a form, try adding this as an index of data in your Ajax Call.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ url('/yourURL') }}",
    data: {
       _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
       formData : myArray,
    },
```

Comment: The CSRF token is sent in the request though. I use `$('input[name=_token]').val()` to add the token to the request.